# Provisioning Oracle's JDK into VirtualBox using Puppet and Vagrant

Tags: ubuntu, puppet, virtualbox, vagrant, java

I am trying to **install Oracle's jdk with Vagrant/Puppet**.

Here is the relevant portion of my `Vagrant file`:

```
  config.vm.provision :puppet, :module_path => "puppet/modules" do |puppet|
     puppet.options = "--verbose --debug"       
     puppet.manifests_path = "puppet/manifests"
     puppet.manifest_file  = "java.pp"
  end
```

and here is my the `java.pp` puppet file:

```
class java {

  package { "python-software-properties":
    require => Exec['apt-update'],
    ensure => installed
  }

  exec { 'add-webupd8-key':
    command => 'sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys EEA14886',
    path => [ "/bin/", "/sbin/" , "/usr/bin/", "/usr/sbin/" ],
  }

  exec { 'apt-update':
    command => 'sudo apt-get update',
    path => [ "/bin/", "/sbin/" , "/usr/bin/", "/usr/sbin/" ],
  }

  exec { "add-apt-repository-oracle":
    command => "sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:webupd8team/java",
    path => [ "/bin/", "/sbin/" , "/usr/bin/", "/usr/sbin/" ],
    require => [Exec["add-webupd8-key"],Package["python-software-properties"]],
#    notify => Exec["apt-update"]
  }

  exec {
    'set-licence-selected':
      command => '/bin/echo debconf shared/accepted-oracle-license-v1-1 select true | /usr/bin/debconf-set-selections';

    'set-licence-seen':
      command => '/bin/echo debconf shared/accepted-oracle-license-v1-1 seen true | /usr/bin/debconf-set-selections';
  }

  package { 'oracle-java7-installer':
#    ensure => "7u40-0~webupd8~0",
    ensure => installed,
    require => [Exec['add-apt-repository-oracle'], Exec['apt-update'], Exec['set-licence-selected'], Exec['set-licence-seen']],
  }
}

include java
```

When I first run `vagrant up`, I always get the following error:

```
debug: Puppet::Type::Package::ProviderApt: Executing '/usr/bin/apt-get -q -y -o DPkg::Options::=--force-confold install oracle-java7-installer'
err: /Stage[main]/Java/Package[oracle-java7-installer]/ensure: change from purged to present failed: Execution of '/usr/bin/apt-get -q -y -o DPkg::Options::=--force-confold install oracle-java7-installer' returned 100: Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
E: Unable to locate package oracle-java7-installer
```

when I **next** run a `vagrant provision`, the **jdk does get installed properly**.

**Can anyone please help me understand why the provisionning does not run smoothly at the vagrant up stage? Also how can I simplify  my java.pp file?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your commented out `notify => Exec["apt-update"]` for `Exec["add-apt-repository-oracle"]` is essential.

Without it, the `apt-get update` is free to run *before* the repository is actually added; `Package['oracle-java7-installer']` is making sure the repo is in place and that the update has been run, but nothing's making sure those happen in the right order.

Might I recommend using the [Puppet Labs `apt` module](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-apt), instead, which will take care of this for you?

```
apt::ppa { 'ppa:webupd8team/java': }

package { 'oracle-java7-installer':
  ensure   => installed,
  require  => Apt::Ppa['ppa:webupd8team/java'],
}
```

Comment: Hi Shane. I am not sure how to use a puppet module... Can you please advise?

Comment: @balteo Should be able to just run `puppet module install puppetlabs/apt` on your master, then use can use the classes defined by the module in other manifests.

Comment: http://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/3/reference/modules_fundamentals.html